# Magento (1.7) specifying a path to translate.csv

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

CURRENT SETUP

I have a multiplie language websites with the following template layout:

```
/frontend/base
/frontend/english
/frontend/portuguese
/frontend/ ...
```

So each site has a separate set of template files in /frontend/[site]/template

I switch between the sites using code in URL, eg,

```
http://mysite/en/..., http://mysite/pt/...
```

I have a translation file for each site in, eg,

```
/frontend/portuguese/[root category]/locale/pt_PT/translate.csv
```

and use `$this->__()` in the .phtml files.

This is all working fine.

---

WHAT I WOULD LIKE

I want all websites to use the `/frontend/base` template files, using `$this->__()`.

The problem I'm having is that files pulled from the `/frontend/base` templates do not find the correct translate.csv file.

So for example, how do I specify that the `/frontend/base` template files should use a `/locale/pt_PT/translate.csv` file when the site is running in Portuguese?

Comment: i think you have not properly updated locale configuration option or store wise or not setting store id as Portuguese in fronted when userr  is coming from Portuguese, Are you auto-swtiching store based on user location, if so check store id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set locale for each store in `System » Configuration » General » locale options » locale(English united states)`. But did you set `System » Configuration » Design » Design Themes » Translations` to your template, too?

***Update***
I think you want to manage your templatefiles in one place. But keep the default template. According to the [theme fallback hierarchy](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy/) the foldertree you are searching might be:

```
base/default/                         #no new files or changes here
your_package/default/locale/pt_PT/translate.csv
your_package/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv
your_package/default/template/        #changes against base/default
your_package/portuguese/template/     #changes against your_package/default
your_package/english/template/        #changes against your_package/default
```

`your_package/default` is your fallback theme when files aren't found in `your_package/portuguese` for example. When files aren't found there `base/default` is your fallback. So if you just want to use translationfiles, you don't need to copy the files from `base/default`.

Comment: I have this set as `[root category]` as in (`/frontend/portuguese/[root category]/locale/pt_PT/translate.csv`). This works fine for normal templates, but not when I want to use templates from `/frontend/base`.

Comment: You have own themes in `base` folder? Themes an translations need to be from the same package.

Comment: That's right @Simon H - but I'm looking for a solution to this. Perhaps I there is a way using a config xml file to override this behaviour?

Comment: Originally I made template changes in the `/frontend/portuguese` folder, but I want to just have one set of template files (`/frontend/base`) BUT still use separate `translate.csv` files for each site.. if that makes sense. The point is, only one set of template files ever need modifying. Cheers.

Comment: It will work if you put your templatechanges in `your_package/default`. Tell me if you need help to configure it in admin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Download language pack for your all stores and put in app/locale

e.g
en_US for english store and so on...

after that go to your admin panel and select your store from left dropdown "Current Configuration Scope:".

**System » Configuration » General » locale options » locale(English united states)**

save configuration. clear cache.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, I already have this. I'm talking about the translate.csv file that I use for adding translation to Template files.